# Get url for the page being opened next in window.onunload event

Tags: javascript, html, onunload, window.onunload

Is there a way get the location for page being opened next in the window.onunload event.

Best Regards,
Keshav

Answer (score 3):

No! That would be a security problem. Imagine someone navigating from a porn site to a banking site. The other way round (with the HTTP Referrer header) is already somewhat a headache. Firefox allows to suppress the referrer:

Enter about:config in the address bar
Search for referer (sic)
Set network.http.sendRefererHeader to 0

(Courtesy to http://cafe.elharo.com/privacy/privacy-tip-3-block-referer-headers-in-firefox/)

Answer (score 0):

The current page cannot and should not know where the user wants to go next (via address bar or bookmarks) (as @nalply said).

If your situation is you want to know which link that the use clicked on your page, then you can do this with javascript. Have a temporary variable that is populated with the URL everytime the user clicks on a link on your page. Then in window.onunload, you can use this.

If this is not your situation, can you tell your specific requirement on why you want to this? Perhaps you might get better solutions if you tell what you are trying to acheive.