# Track the new url being entered in the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I want to track the new url being entered in the browser when the user leaves the current page in the onunload event.

If the user is browsing www.xyz.com/page1.aspx and suddenly he types a new URL in the browser, I want to get the new url typed in the onunload event. Is that possbile ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i get the destination url in javascript onbeforeunload event?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event)

Comment: Not only is this a duplicate question, but there is no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI. Someone else asked similar question.

[How can i get the destination url in javascript onbeforeunload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event)

[Get url for the page being opened next in window.onunload event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186722/get-url-for-the-page-being-opened-next-in-window-onunload-event)